# Как получить доступ к файловой системе смартфона?

Tags: c#, файлы

Работаю с накопителями в файловой системе через DriveInfo. Однако, если подключить к компьютеру смартфон, то DriveInfo.GetDrives() не находит его. В то же время имя  смартфона отображается в проводнике Windows, и через него можно спокойно работать с файловой системой смартфона.
Вопрос: как получить доступ к хранилищу на смартфоне?

Comment: Какой смартфон? Windows Phone?

Comment: Android. Но идея в том, чтобы получать доступ к любому телефону :)

Comment: А обычную флешку видит? Или только жесткие диски?

Comment: Флешки видит. Не видит только телефоны.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DriveInfo` выдает информацию только о removable devices. Смартфоны попадают в категорию portable devices.

Варианты:

- использовать Windows Portable Devices API ([репо на гитхабе с примерами кода](https://github.com/geersch/WPD), [блог команды WPD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dimeby8/))
- использовать библиотеку [PortableDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PortableDevices/) (основана на примерах из вышеупомянутого репо)
- для взаимодействия с Андроидом можно воспользоваться библиотекой [AndroidLib](https://github.com/regaw-leinad/AndroidLib) ([топик на XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685))